# What happens between the end of the last series and the 50th anniversary special?

Tags: doctor-who, timeline, the-day-of-the-doctor

Lots of spoilers, obviously.

At the end of the last series, in *The Name of the Doctor*:

> The Doctor and Clara are forced to travel to Trenzalore by the Great Intelligence, where Clara steps into the Doctor's grave - a scar in spacetime where she is scattered across his history. The 11th Doctor jumps in to save her and it ends on a cliffhanger where they meet the War Doctor for the first time.

Then in the 50th anniversary special *The Day of the Doctor*:

> It starts with Clara working as a teacher and the Doctor travelling.

How? What happened between these two episodes? The 11th Doctor mentions Clara having met 'Mr Grumpy' before, but there seems to be some missing narrative. Have I missed a special or something?

> How do Clara and the Doctor escape from the Doctor's grave on Trenzalore?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite maybe, but I searched the site first and didn't find that question. If it is a dupe it's one that might better help users find it.

Comment: @MrLister how do you know?

Comment: @Keith: very true, it might do. With regards to Trenzalore’s spelling, here’s a couple of references from the BBC website with that spelling: http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/doctorwho/articles/Matt-Smith-to-leave-Doctor-Who, http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/galleries/p0195kps, http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/doctorwho/articles/A-Beginners-Guide-to-the-Doctors.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite cheers, corrected :-)

Answer (score 8):

### We have no idea.

Sorry, but it's that simple. You haven't missed anything. They obviously got out of the Doctor's timeline somehow, but we have been given nothing to go on. There's just a great big gap between the "But not in the name of the Doctor!" climax of *The Name of the Doctor* and Clara's callout-laden appearance as a teacher in *The Day of the Doctor*.

Comment: it's particularly confusing because the end of *Name*, one would think, ought to be particularly memorable for Clara, but she doesn't recognize WarDoctor when she sees him.